# Static files - Django Azure

Tags: django, azure, static

I am hosting a website on Microsoft Azure. I have updated all the configurations within Azure and my settings.py file looks as below -

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.azure_storage.AzureStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storage.custom_azure.AzureStaticStorage'

AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME = os.environ.get('AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME')
AZURE_STORAGE_KEY = os.environ.get('AZURE_STORAGE_KEY', False)
AZURE_MEDIA_CONTAINER = os.environ.get('AZURE_MEDIA_CONTAINER', 'media')
AZURE_STATIC_CONTAINER = os.environ.get('AZURE_STATIC_CONTAINER', 'static')
AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AZURE_STATIC_CONTAINER}/'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AZURE_MEDIA_CONTAINER}/'
STATIC_ROOT = f'https://{AZURE_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AZURE_STATIC_CONTAINER}/'
```

I have a custom_storage folder with a custom_azure.py file with following -

```
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.azure_storage import AzureStorage

class AzureMediaStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name = settings.AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
    account_key = settings.AZURE_STORAGE_KEY
    azure_container = settings.AZURE_MEDIA_CONTAINER
    expiration_secs = None


class AzureStaticStorage(AzureStorage):
    account_name = settings.AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME
    account_key = settings.AZURE_STORAGE_KEY
    azure_container = settings.AZURE_STATIC_CONTAINER
    expiration_secs = None
```

However I am now pulling a static admin file and not the static project file containing css, scss and js files..

Answer (score 0):

As a work around the the install of whitenoise enables the static files when hosting on Azure. However does not solve the problem of storing the static files on the Azure platform.